# Element.animate() in HTML4

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, chromium

It seems the people at Chrome have [appropriated Element.animate()](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/05/Web-Animations---element-animate-is-now-in-Chrome-36) for themselves, effectively breaking all existing HTML pages using something along the lines of `onclick="animate();"`.

Is this legal for a browser under the HTML 4/Transitional spec? Is this something that W3C would formally have authority over?

Is there anything small-time website owners can do to prevent any further transgressions of this sort?

EDIT:
Test Case:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function animate() {
            alert('this should work');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="animate();" value="push me!">
</body>
</html>
```

Results in `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.` on Chrome, but works in FireFox.

Comment: I'm pretty sure nobody can prevent Google from doing pretty much anything.

Comment: The `.animate()` method is defined by a [currently-in-draft specification](http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/web-animations/) hosted by W3C (linked in the 3rd paragraph of the article). It isn't just for Chrome and stands a good chance at seeing adoption by other browsers. One option to avoid conflicts is to [avoid depending on obtrusive/embedded JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and the implied `with (this) {}` block that `onevent` attributes use.

Comment: I'm not sure they've "appropriated" anything. They've added a method to the prototype of elements in the DOM, probably according to some draft standard being worked on with other browser vendors. I'm not even sure your example is affected, because surely `animate()` there will look for `window.animate()` whereas the new method would be `this.animate()`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about whether browsers must be standards-compliant and is not about programming.

Comment: @IMSoP Doe the draft standards intend to break HTML 4? Also, I added test code to demonstrate that this is a real issue.

Comment: Attach event listeners properly, and you’ll be fine.

Comment: It seems I was wrong, and `this.animate` is used if set. However, you can always qualify the function name explicitly to run a global function. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/bKB8E/4/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The change you are referring to is not a unilateral move by Google, but part of a [draft W3C standard called Web Animations 1.0](http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/web-animations/). The specific modification you are running into trouble with is [the extension to the DOM `Element` interface](http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/web-animations/#extensions-to-the-element-interface) which adds three new methods, including `animate()`:

> Since DOM Elements may be the target of an animation, the Element interface [DOM4] is extended as follows: `Element implements Animatable;`
>
> This allows the following kind of usage. `elem.animate({ color: 'red' }, 2000);`

DOM here stands for "Document Object Model", which is [another standard, separate from HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/) which defines how JavaScript and other languages should expose and interact with an HTML, XML, or similar document. This standard has had many expansions over the years, so the addition of this new method to `Element` objects is by no means unprecedented or likely to be controversial.

---

Your specific problem is one of *namespace collision*. JavaScript's scoping rules are relatively complex in any situation, and when you embed an event handler in an HTML attribute, there is some special logic, as explained in [this MDN article about "event attributes"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Event_attributes).

The upshot is that when you write `onclick="animate();"`, `animate` is looked up as a property in multiple scopes, or namespaces, including:

- as a property of the clicked element, which has been bound to `this`; if found, `animate()` will behave the same as `this.animate()`
- as a property of the global `window` object, which is always the last scope checked in any situation; thus if nothing else is found, `animate()` will be equivalent to `window.animate()`

Your problem is that you are relying on something being called from the global namespace, but the changes to the DOM mean that it is now defined on `this` as well (specifically, it is in the prototype of all descendants of `Element`). Since the new function takes precedence over your existing one, an unexpected behaviour change occurs.

The simplest fix to your code is therefore to qualify your event more specifically, as `onclick="window.animate();"`. You should do this not just for methods and variables you know have conflicts now, but on all of them, so that they won't be affected by other changes to the DOM in future. ([Here is a demo of that approach](http://jsfiddle.net/bKB8E/4/).)

---

However, if you want to make your code more robust, there are more extensive changes you should make to bring it in line with more up to date coding practices:

- Rather than using "event attributes" such as `onclick`, add event listeners programmatically. The modern API for this is [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), although many people prefer a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) which makes it easier to work with different browsers, and simplifies common tasks (in this case, you'd use [the `.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)).
- Rather than putting functions into a global scope, make them properties of some object, so that you can keep track of your own namespaces. Even better, if you keep them separate from the HTML (using something like `addEventListener` or jQuery's `.on`), you can make them *private* variables, not even accessible from global scope, by using an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IIFE) (an enclosing function which exists only to create a new variable scope).

Comment: Awesome answer, might be worth mentioning that the IIFE approach should be used with `.addEventListener()` or jQuery's `.on()`, to not leave anyone wondering how to attach DOM listeners from an isolated scope.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Right, I'd tried to imply that the second best practice suggestion relied on the first, but I've made it a bit more explicit to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Oh great. `=]` It was clear enough for me, but assuming a possible future reader who has only ever used inline event attributes, reading that point in isolation would seem unclear. Thanks for the edit. `=]`