# Failed to execute "scroll" on "Window" : 2 arguments required, but only 0 given

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

As far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with my syntax, yet the function fails to execute (with the title thrown to Chrome/Opera's error parser) Does anyone know why?

HTML:

```
<div id="shifterSouth" class="shifters" onclick="scroll()"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function scroll(){
    move('#menu')
        .sub('top', window.innerHeight)
        .end();

    move('#splash')
        .sub('top', window.innerHeight)
        .end();
}
```

I'm using the [move.js](http://visionmedia.github.io/move.js/) library for animations.

Comment: You mean the function doesn't get called at all? Did you put an `alert()` at the first line to confirm, or use a debugger?

Comment: @1sand0s I think he means he gets the error message in the title.

Comment: There already is a scroll function, the `window.scroll` function, which takes two arguments. Give your function another name and make sure it's in the right scope.

Comment: You have a name collision; check out this answer for an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24872330/157957

Comment: @adeneo - why don't you make an answer if that's the issue here.

Comment: @jfriend00 - one should be able to overwrite the `scroll` function, even in the global scope, so the functions name probably isn't the real issue, it's probably out of scope, defined inside DOM ready or something, and then because of that `window.scroll` is called instead, and that error comes up because `window.scroll` requires two arguments.

Comment: Yes, if the handler was attached in DOM ready instead of HTML this _should_ work.

Comment: Thanks guys, turned out it was a name clash and scripts too far down the document. If someone posts an "answer" I'll accept that and close the question.